# Splitting field and Galois group of $f := x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 ∈ \mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Hey I want to check if my solutions for this problem are right:

Show that the polynomial $f := x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1 ∈ \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is irreducible and determine the splitting field $E$ of $f$ and the Galois group $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$

Since $f$ Cyclotomic polynomial it is irreducible.
$E=\mathbb{Q}(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}=: \xi)$

The degree of the extension is $[E:\mathbb{Q}]=4$, right?

So we have $[E:\mathbb{Q}]=4=Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$

And $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})=\{\tau_1,...,\tau_4\}$

Where $\tau_i: \xi \rightarrow \xi^i$ and therefore is $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Comment: Compare with the post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/766656/galois-group-for-x5-1), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342549/the-galois-group-of-x5-1-over-the-rational-numbers), for example. The general case is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709216/the-galois-group-of-xn-1-is-isomorphic-to-z-nzx), so the Galois group of $X^n-1$ is $U(n)=(\Bbb Z/n)^{\times}$ of order $\phi(n)$. For $n=5$ this group is cyclic of order $4$, yes. In general, $U(n)$ is only cyclic for $n=p^k,2p^k,2,4$, $p>2$ prime.

Comment: In the second link it is mentioned that $X^5-1=(X-1)(X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1)$, so that the Galois group is the same for your polynomial and $X^5-1$.